# get the ful imagepath for any image on the web

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I get any image tag from any website I want to be able to get the full path to the image file.

eg:

```
src="http://www.example.com/images/foo.gif" //This is fine

src="images/foo.gif"

src="/images/foo.gif"
```

for the bottom two src attributes, how can i get the full image path?
I want to treat the src attribute universally and always get the full path of an image.

Comment: What information do you know about the page that hosts the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have the url of the page that holds the image, and the url of the image, you can use `new Uri(pageUri, imageUri)` to combine the urls and get the full url